# Confused at the filter() function and I need an in depth explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, data-structures, filter

I have just started to learn java script and the concept of the filter() function is confusing to me.

```
a.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
```

Above is a code snippet where the filter function shows an array without duplicates, lets assume `a` is an array with many duplicate numbers.

I 100% don't understand what is going on in the block of code. I know that the filter function returns a boolean value but what does `item` mean in this equation? What does `pos` mean? If the filter function returns a boolean then why does this equation return an array of numbers that are non duplicate?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the `filter` function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter It explains what the arguments to the callback function are.

Comment: Filter doesn't return a boolean, it returns a filtered array. If the callback returns `true`, then item is included in the result, if false it's not. In this case, the predicate is - does the the current index of the item (`pos`), is the same as the index of the item in the array. If not, the item is a duplicate, and we'll be filtered out. Read a bit about [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` doesn't return a boolean, it returns an array containing elements of the original array. It decides which elements to include in the result by calling a function that you supply on each element of the array. This function returns a boolean: if it's truthy, that element is included in the result. The arguments to the function are the element (called `item` in your function) and its position in the array (called `pos`).

This function uses `indexOf()` to find the position of the first element in the array that has the same value as the element it was given. If that position is the same as the position it was given, then this element must be the first occurrence of that value in the array, so it returns `true` and the element will be included in the result. If the positions are different, then this element must be a later duplicate, so it returns `false` and the element is not included in the result. The final result of this is that only the first copy of each value is included in the resulting of filtering, which means they're all unique.

For instance, suppose the array is:

```
["a", "b", "a", "c"]
```

On the first iteration, `item = "a"` and `pos = 0`. `a.indexOf(item)` returns `0`, and the function returns `0 == 0`, which is `true`, so `item` is included in the result.

On the second iteration, `item = "b"` and `pos = 1`. `a.indexOf(item)` returns `1`, and the function returns `1 == 1`, which is `true`, so `item` is included in the result.

On the third iteration, `item == "a"` and `pos = 2`. `a.indexOf(item)` returns `0`, and the function returns `0 == 2`, which is `false`, so `item` is *not* included in the result.

On the fourth iteration, `item = "c"` and `pos = 3`. `a.indexOf(item)` returns `3`, and the function returns `3 == 3`, which is `true`, so `item` is included in the result.

The final result is that the items from the first, second, and fourth iterations are included in the result, which is `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: Does that mean that `pos` corresponds as an index to each element in the array? So lets say the array is at `[1, 2, 1, 3]` and I filter the array with the same function syntax as shown above. Does it mean for the first iteration the arguments passed will be `function(1, 0)`? When the iteration goes through again it would be `function(2, 1)`. `2` signifying the element and `1` signifying the index. But wouldn't the 3rd iteration be `function(1, 2)`?

I just need to break it down as simple as possible.

Comment: I've added a full example of 4 iterations.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation! You sir are a scholar and a gentleman!

Answer (score 0):

The filter 'callback' parameter returns a 'Boolean' ; The filter function returns the filtered array.